# How to use the methods pop() or shift() inside of an ngrx selector?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

Hi in my redux store a carerequest has one or more appointments, i am working with a list of carerequests where the first time a carerequest is rendered it should pick the first appointment and the second time the second appointment but we can't use pop or shift inside of our selector does anyone know a work around or how we should use pop() or shift() inside of an ngrx selector or could we dispatch an action inside of our selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pop()` and `shift()` are mutable functions. And the state of the store should be read-only.

You can imagine something like this:

```
export const selectFilteredRequests = createSelector(
  selectRequests,
  (requests: Request[]) => {
     const result = [...requests];
     result.pop() // Or result.shift()
     return result
  }
);
```

Comment: But if i call this selector twice it still returns the same list eventhough pop is called twice on this list do you have any idea how to adjust this in the store from this selector?

Comment: What do you mean by calling the selector twice?

Comment: Using the ```selectFilteredRequests``` inside of a component inside of a for loop will return the same first request for each component instead of the second request for the second component of the loop in case of returning result.pop instead of result inside of  the selector